# How to export a Crypto key in python?

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I want to encrypt files fore secure storage, but the problem is, I don't know how to store the key to decrypt the files afterwards.

Code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import ast

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)

encrypteds = str()

for text in open('passwords.log', 'rb').readlines():

    publickey = key.publickey()

    encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(publickey)
    encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(text)

    decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
    decrypted = decryptor.decrypt(ast.literal_eval(str(encrypted)))

    print(publickey)
    encrypteds+=str(encrypted)+'--|--'

with open('passwords_encrypted.log', 'w') as out:
    out.write(str(encrypted))
```

Comment: There are two many symmetrical and asymmetrical encryption in cryptography and cryptanalysis scheme you could apply for secure encryption decryption key derivation key sharing between parties or an entities etc. E.g AES Chaha20Poly1305 AESGCM but its depends on on what kind of encryption scheme you want to apply. It is sensitive critical point. please have look you definitely find your answer as well
http://legrandin.github.io/pycryptodome/Doc/3.3.1/Crypto.Cipher-module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're encrypting data makes no sense. Asymmetric encryption can only encrypt a small, fixed amount of data. Never use asymmetric encryption such as RSA-OAEP for anything other than a symmetric key, and use that symmetric key to encrypt the actual data. For the symmetric encryption, use a proper AEAD mode such as AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305. This is called [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Other things that are wrong with your code:

- A 1024-bit RSA key is not enough for security: 2048-bit is a minimum, and you should prepare to move away from RSA because its key sizes don't scale well. (Feel free to use 1024-bit keys for testing and learning, just don't use anything less than 2048-bit for RSA in production.)
- The encryption is a binary format, but you join up lines as if they were text. Text or binary: pick one. Preferably use a well-known format such as ASN.1 (complex but well-supported) for binary data or JSON for text. If you need to encode binary data in a text format, use Base64.

If this is for real-world use, scrap this and use [NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to) or [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/). In Python, use a Python wrapper such as [libnacl](https://libnacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [PyNaCl](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [pysodium](https://pypi.org/project/pysodium/) or [csodium](https://github.com/ereOn/csodium). Use a [public-key box](https://libnacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/public.html). The Python APIs are slightly different for each Python wrapper, but all include a way to export the keys.

If this is a learning exercise, read up on hybrid encryption. Look inside libsodium to see how to do it correctly. Key import and export is done with the methods [`import_key`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.import_key) and [`export_key`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.export_key). Symmetric encryption starts with [`Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(key, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_GCM)`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#gcm-mode) or [`Crypto.Cipher.ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key)`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20_poly1305.html#Crypto.Cipher.ChaCha20_Poly1305.new) (`Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(key, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)` or `Crypto.Cipher.ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key, nonce=nonce)` for decryption).

Comment: Thank you! This programm schould be an exercise since I have never touched encoding bevore. These tips are really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I look at your code but RSA currently many issues of security so please considers another type of encryption as read attentively and follow. There are two many symmetrical and asymmetrical encryption in cryptography and cryptanalysis scheme you could apply for secure encryption decryption key derivation key sharing between parties or an entities etc. E.g AES Chaha20Poly1305 AESGCM but its depends on on what kind of encryption scheme you want to apply. It is sensitive critical point. please have look you definitely find your answer as well check and suggest you to look at the others symmetric encryption which have good security as compare to RSA. http://legrandin.github.io/pycryptodome/Doc/3.3.1/Crypto.Cipher-module.html